# How to capture text in different format through for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, txt

the original txt data is:

```
2021/12/20(週二)
21:34   狼   今天一個單
想請教~
這是什麼？
21:35   全   我誰  哈哈哈
21:35   全   很多
21:36   哥   對話
```

I tried to used these code to capture the text data.

```
data <- data.frame(user_name = c(),date = c(), date = c())
date <- vector(length=length(filedata)) 
time <- vector(length=length(filedata))
user_name <- vector(length=length(filedata))
text <- vector(length=length(filedata))

pat1 = '[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}'  
pat2 = '[0-9]+:[0-9]+'               
for(i in 1: length(filedata)){
  dt_pattern1 <- grepl(pat1,filedata[i]) 
  dt_pattern2 <- grepl(pat2,filedata[i]) 
  if(dt_pattern1 == TRUE){
    date[i] <- substr(filedata[i],1,nchar(filedata[i])-4)
  }
  if(dt_pattern2 == TRUE){
    time[i] <- str_split(filedata[i], "\\s+", simplify = T)[, 1]
    user_name[i] <-  str_split(filedata[i], "\\s+", simplify = T)[, 2]
    text[i] <- substr(filedata[i], nchar(user_name[i])+ nchar(time[i])+2, nchar(filedata[i]))
  }
}

data <- rbind(data, data.frame(Name = user_name,date = date,time = time, text = text))
```

but what I get is:

```
21:34   狼 今天一個單
21:35   全  我誰  哈哈哈
21:35   全  很多
21:36   哥  對話
```

which I also need the text without date format in the beginning:

```
想請教~
這是什麼？
```

Can I ask how can I capture these text through for loop?

The problem of capturing the text is solvable, but how could it merge with other text data in correct time is another hard issues, which the outcome that it need to be is:

```
21:34   狼   今天一個單
21:34   狼   想請教~
21:34   狼   這是什麼？
21:35   全   我誰  哈哈哈
21:35   全   很多
21:36   哥   對話
```

Comment: I tried to used '/^(?![0-9]+:[0-9]+).*$/' to capture, but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you must absolutely use for-loops, I would instead use the `tidyr` package for this kind of data cleaning.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

filedata <- readr::read_csv(
  "2021/12/20(週二)
  21:34   狼   今天一個單
  想請教~
  這是什麼？
  21:35   全   我誰  哈哈哈
  21:35   全   很多
  21:36   哥   對話",
col_names = FALSE)

filedata %>%
  filter(!grepl('^\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\(\\w+\\)$', X1)) %>%
  separate(X1, into = c('time', 'user_name', 'text'), sep = '   ', fill = 'left') %>%
  fill(c(time, user_name), .direction = 'down')

#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   time  user_name text        
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>       
#> 1 21:34 狼        今天一個單  
#> 2 21:34 狼        想請教~     
#> 3 21:34 狼        這是什麼？  
#> 4 21:35 全        我誰  哈哈哈
#> 5 21:35 全        很多        
#> 6 21:36 哥        對話
```